# How to wait for server to come up and run unit test from Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: unit-testing, ant, junit, web, jenkins

This is pretty simple question. I am posting this because I couldn't get any satisfying answer. First the background: I have Jenkins job that builds and deploys a web application on to a server. The server takes some time (in the order of 5 to 10 minutes). I would like to setup a job (or modify the existing as required) to rig up the unit test case execution which will test the application. I am thinking of the following approaches. I would like you to validate or suggest any alternatives:

- Have an Ant target that waits for a fixed time
- Have a custom Ant target which pings the URL and checks for app availability

Thanks in advance for your help.
-Vadiraj.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Waiting for a fixed time has the problem that the time you choose is either to short (build fails) or to long (waste of build time). So I think it would be better to check if the app is available.

I have done something similar for my Selenium tests. I had to wait until the Selenium Remote Server has started. I used the `waitfor` element. For a detailled documentation see [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html).

Here is a stripped down version of my ant-Target:

```
<parallel>
  <sequential>
    ... Start web application server ...
  </sequential>
  <sequential>
    <waitfor maxwait="10" maxwaitunit="minute">
      <socket server="localhost" port="8080" />
    </waitfor>
    <junit>
    ...
    </junit>
  </sequential>
</parallel>
```

If your server is available before the web app is deployed you can try to use the `http` condition instead of `socket` to check for a HTTP error code. The conditions are documented [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).